# Django: UserCreationForm not showing

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a user sign-up form. It largely works, except that the form does not show in the template. My base template renders, just not the form itself. I get no traceback errors, the page (aside from the "base.html" template) is blank i.e. white space, with not even a button.

I'm trying to recreate the tutorial done here: https://wsvincent.com/django-user-authentication-tutorial-signup/

signup.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}Sign Up{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h2>Sign up</h2>
  <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

accounts/urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'accounts'

urlpatterns = [
     path('signup/', views.SignUp.as_view(), name='signup'),
]
```

myproject/urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from clincher import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('clincher/', include('clincher.urls'), name='clincher'),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls')),
    path('accounts/', include('django.contrib.auth.urls'), name='accounts'),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='clincher/templates/')),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views import generic

class SignUp(generic.CreateView):
    form_class = UserCreationForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('login')
    template_name = 'signup.html'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem in your template.

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

Change your code in template from above to the following one:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
</form>
```

When you give it as `form.p` the template engine searches for an attribute with name 'p' inside 'form' object, but that is not what we want. So use `form.as_p` instead to render the form wrapped in paragraph elements.

Comment: hmm, good thought. I thought this would have solved the problem, but the form still shows up blank

Comment: Can you please post the log records which you got on console when you navigated to the signup page. It can help me in debugging your problem.

Comment: [16/Jun/2018 07:12:43] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 4205 -----
[16/Jun/2018 07:12:50] "GET /accounts/login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 4292 -----
[16/Jun/2018 07:12:53] "GET /accounts/signup/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3786 ----- Is this what you meant?

Comment: Once try inspecting your webpage by right clicking and inspect element. Check whether the HTML code of base and the content template both are present.

Comment: You were right. It was a small problem in my template that was not showing the form. The `{% block content %}` in the tutorial should have been `{%block body %}` in my program. But thanks, you found the bug, and it was in my html template!. Well done.